# Add CKEDITOR on Dynamiclly generated inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am generating two text inputs on a single button click. here, i want to add CKEDITOR on both generated elements. 
Here is my code to populate the elements

```
       var html ='<div class="form-group" style="border:1px solid #eee;padding:3px;"><i class="fa fa-remove fa-remove-content-block" style="float:right;cursor:pointer"></i>';
    html+='<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ckedit_new_add_content_title" name="section_title[]" required="required" />';
    html+='<textarea class="form-control" id="ckedit_new_add_content_desc" name="suburb_content[]" style="margin-top:10px"></textarea></div>';

    $(this).parent().append(html);
```

Any Solution  please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to check out this repo.[.ckeditor][1]

[1]: https://github.com/samcyn/CK_EDITOR-With-TABS dynamically created input have their own instances of ckeditor. It will save you some time to check it out. Best wishes